# Why does the value of all lists (in a list) change if I change only one?

Tags: c#, list, nested-lists

I need a dynamically 2D list like this `List<List<Boolean>>`. As soon as i change a value in an inner list it changes all values in that position of all inner lists.

For example:

I have 3 lists in a list:

```
Boolean t = true;
Boolean f = false;
List<Boolean> temp = new List<Boolean>();
List<List<Boolean>> list = new List<List<Boolean>>();

void createLists()
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        temp.Clear();
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            temp.Add(f);        //{f, f, f}
        }
        list.Add(temp);         //list[0] = {f, f, f}
    }                           //list[1] = {f, f, f}
}                               //list[2] = {f, f, f}
```

and I am now only changing **one** value of an inner list:

```
void changeValue()
{
    list[0][0] = t;
}
```

`list[0]` equals now `{t, f, f}` and `list[1]` and `list[2]` should still equal `{f, f, f}` BUT instead `list[1]` and `list[2]` are both `{t, f, f}`.

So my Matrix is:

```
{{t, f, f},
 {t, f, f},
 {t, f, f}}
```

instead of:

```
{{t, f, f},
 {f, f, f},
 {f, f, f}}
```

same problem if i use `list[0].RemoveAt(2);`

Comment: Because you only create one `List<bool>` so you really have a list with multiple reference to the same list.  You should move the creation of `temp` inside of the first `for` loop

Comment: `temp.Clear();` will clear the same list each time. And `list.Add(temp);` will add the same (overwritten) list each time. Both because `temp` is a `List<T>`, which is a [reference type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/reference-types). Move the declaration of `temp` inside the loop instead of using `.Clear()`.

Comment: Because you are adding the same `temp` to `list` multiple times. You just do `tmp.clear()`. This removes all elements from the list, but does not create a new one. Do `temp = new List<bool>()` instead of `temp.Clear()` to create a new lisr

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your `temp` list is always the same object reference.

```
Boolean t = true;
Boolean f = false;

List<List<Boolean>> list = new List<List<Boolean>>();

void createLists()
{
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        var temp = new List<Boolean>();
        for(int j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            temp.Add(f);        
        }
        list.Add(temp);         
    }                           
}
```

With this change you add always a new List<> object to your 2D list.